# NestedScrolling with NestedScrollView, RecyclerView (Horizontal), inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout, nestedscrollview

I have a UI design with CollapsingToolbarLayout, like following.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <!-- Hiding unrelated code -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:padding="16dp">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_movie_suggestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My problem is, the scrolling is fine ONLY when I touch and scroll the area OUTSIDE the RecyclerView. If I try to scroll vertically inside the RecyclerView, the scrolling is "trapped" and ONLY the NestedScrollView is scrolling, the CollaspingToolbarLayout ISN'T collasping.

Comment: It think it is a bug, the nestedScrollingEnabled can only be done in code. doing it in XML has no effect.

Answer (score 36):

You need to disable nested scrolling programatically. It doesn't seem to work correctly if done in xml.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: shall I consider that non-working xml attribute as bug?

Comment: If my Screen is large, which the NestedScrollView can be fully displayed (or mostly, if including the height of the CollaspingToolbarLayout, which makes some overdraw in the bottom), the above solution doesn't work. Seems No event is sent to CollaspingToolbarLayout to make it collasping.

Comment: I think that's true even without an inner RecyclerView

Comment: Works for me Great answer. Thanks @karaokyo.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much @tachyonflux

Answer (score 3):

This is most common issue while using recyclerview inside nestedscrollview.

I have fixed this by adding following lines into xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey if you're interested I created a LayoutManager that should solve your problem.

```java
public class ExpansiveLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

public ExpansiveLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpansiveLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public ExpansiveLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
}
```

https://github.com/emanuelet/LayoutManagers/blob/master/ExpansiveLayoutManager.java

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put your recyclerView inside NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/recycler_movie_suggestion"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="170dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use NestedScrollView. Just leave LinearLayout there.